# In ASP.net, How to Achieve Same Url But Different Page Depending on Logged In/Out?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, redirect, twitter

I see this in both Twitter and Facebook - the URL of the front page (where you log in) is the same as the main timeline page once you've logged in.

I don't think it's a redirect. I don't think it's a MultiView with a view open for each case.

Which ASP.net technology would best achieve this?

Comment: Use `MVC` and return a different view depending on whether the user is logged in or not?

Answer (score 0):

MVC not necessarily needed. Two `<div>` elements, one containing the content for "not Logged in" and one containing content for "logged in" - show or hide as appropriate ?

Of course this is roughly what a MultiView does as well..